# OTS parsing error: invalid version tag

Tags: webpack, fonts

I generated my font-icons using icomoon.io and the resulting style.css has a bunch of fonts in `@font-face` as shown below:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'nf-icons';
  src:  url('/sass/icons/fonts/nf-icons.eot?ar4irv');
  src:  url('/sass/icons/fonts/nf-icons.eot?ar4irv#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('/sass/icons/fonts/nf-icons.ttf?ar4irv') format('truetype'),
    url('/sass/icons/fonts/nf-icons.woff?ar4irv') format('woff'),
    url('/sass/icons/fonts/nf-icons.svg?ar4irv#nf-icons') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

notice that `/sass/icons` is the base path of my project and has been added so that webpack is able to resolve the paths.

Here are the rules I've written in my webpack config

```
{
    test: /\.woff(2)?(\?[a-z0-9#=&.]+)?$/,
    use: 'url-loader'
},
{
    test: /\.(jpg|png|svg|ttf|eot)(\?[a-z0-9#=&.]+)?$/,
    use: 'file-loader'
}
```

webpack compiles without any errors. However, the browser complains about not being able to decode the font.

[image]

I've gone over multiple solutions on stackoverflow and nothing is fixing this. Please help me understand the reason why is this happening?